# Reverse Crosstab Query in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

In Access 2013, my table has the following structure:

```
Name   |City   |Q113   |Q213
Peter  |London |20     |30
Sandra |Paris  |40     |50
```

I want to "reverse a crosstab query", getting the following:

```
Name   |City   |Period   |Value
Peter  |London |Q113     |20
Peter  |London |Q213     |30
Sandra |Paris  |Q113     |40
Sandra |Paris  |Q213     |50
```

I tried a Union query, using SQL:

```
SELECT [Name], [City] ,'Q113' AS [Period], [Q113] AS [Value]
FROM [Database]
UNION ALL
ORDER BY [Name]
       , [City]
       , [Period]
```

However, it isn't working, I keep getting the error: "Invalid SQL statement expected; 'DELETE','INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT' or 'UPDATE'

Googling this error didn't help much, so I guess there is something wrong with the code above? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the query after your `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT [Name], [City] ,'Q113' AS [Period], [Q113] AS [Value]
FROM [Database]
UNION ALL
SELECT [Name], [City] ,'Q213' AS [Period], [Q213] AS [Value]
FROM [Database]
ORDER BY [Name], [City], [Period]
```

You need to add the second part of your query and then place the ORDER BY last.